# Spider Technology Behind Video Aggregators like SideReel?

Tags: drupal, video, content-management-system, web-crawler, aggregate

Can someone explain to me the aggregation technology behind sites like SideReel?

For example http://www.sidereel.com/the_nine_lives_of_chloe_king/season-1/episode-3/links/9080517

Did they make a spider that automatically fetch the embed links from video owners website like Hulu? Or did they submit all the video links manually?

I'm planning to build a smaller version of video aggregator. Should I use a CMS system like Drupal or code everything from scratch? Any recommendations? I prefer minimal coding because I already have another major component that requires a lot of time.

Thank you all!